# Can I make a `new mysqli()` into a php class?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to connect to mysql database (with mysqli) into a php class. When I do this, by `new mysqli(params)`, I get the

> unexpected 'new'

error. How can I do this? My idea is something like this:

```
<?php


class DbConnection
{
    public $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","todo");



    function RegisterUsers($username, $password, $ip, $name)
    {
        $stmt = $this->$conn->preapre("INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, ip, Name) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $username, $password, $ip, $name);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

}

$dbConn = new DbConnection();
$dbConn->RegisterUsers("a","a","a","a");

?>
```

Comment: Is your class in a namespace?

Comment: All my code is here ;P @Machavity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error here:

```
public $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","todo");
```

Create connection instance in constructor and modify you code as follow:

```
class DbConnection
{
    public $conn;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","todo");
    }

    function RegisterUsers($username, $password, $ip, $name)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, ip, Name) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $username, $password, $ip, $name);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

}
```

Also you have a typo `preapre` and do not need `$` while using `$conn` property inside the object

Comment: Yup, solved! But... now, at line 15(after the RegisterUsers), I get a `Call to undefined method mysqli::preapre()`. Why?

Comment: Worked. But it doesn't insert the values to the database :"(
All the names are correct...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to asssing the value outside a function, try this

```
class A{
    __construct(){
        $Conn = new mysqli(params);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialise objects in the place you've put it. Do it in a construct:

```
class DbConnection
{
    public $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","todo");
    }

    function RegisterUsers($username, $password, $ip, $name)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, ip, Name) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $username, $password, $ip, $name);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

}
```

Comment: Yup, solved! But... now, at line 15(after the RegisterUsers), I get a `Call to undefined method mysqli::preapre()`. Why?

Comment: You spelt it wrong, should be `prepare`. Will add that fix to my code

Comment: Hi, this code doesn't insert the values to the database :"( All the names are correct. I've been working on it for an hour and still didnt find the answer...